# Tips or suggestions for the architecture of the application

Tags: angularjs

I have one problem and want to ask for a "angularjs way" to solve it properly. 
I have a several services that will be used into me application. Before using it I must use login service and "log in" 
the user. So I also have a service that returns status of user - AUTHENTICATED or NOTAUTHENTICATED. I using ngRoute.  Me first idea was to put the check for user status into service and call if in every controller. If the user is not authenticated I will display login popup. Other option is to use global event but I don't like it. So what is the best way?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO the best way would be to put login functionality in a service that way it can be easily injected where necessary. You can check if user is authenticated when he is interacting with a backend service.

i.e. angularjs do http/resource call to backend for a `listOfUsers` then backend either returns valid json or it returns response with login specific failure, then you can that kind of response process in angularjs and display a loginbox